# Android Pause and Resume Background Activity

Tags: android, multithreading, handler

In one activity of my app, there are an imagview and a textview that are changing every 3 seconds.

I first set this up with a handler and thread runnable. It works fine, but when I use removeCallbacks with the pause button, it will not pause in the middle of the Thread. It completes the Thread runnable before pausing. I need it to pause when the button is clicked no matter where it is in the runnable.

I thought about using an asynctask but I'm not sure how this would work.

I know there has to be a way to do this, as you can pause almost any game you download. Does anyone have any suggestions on the best/easiest way to do this?

Thanks so much!! :)

```
public class Workout extends AppCompatActivity {

private String[] messages = {"1", "2", "3", "4", "5"};
final Handler handler = new Handler();
private int nextIndex;
String mDrawableName[] = {"bodypart70", "equipment70", "settings70", "time70", "bodypart70"};
private int nextImage;
ImageView image;
private ProgressBar progressBar;
private int progressStatus = 0;
Runnable r = null;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.workout);

    image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.exerciseImage);
    final TextView text = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView4);
    progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar1);


    //changing
    r = new Runnable(){
        @Override
        public void run(){
            if (messages.length > nextIndex) {

                //change textview
                text.setText(messages[nextIndex++]);
                //change image
                int resID = getResources().getIdentifier(mDrawableName[nextImage++] , "drawable", getPackageName());
                image.setImageResource(resID);
                //restart progress bar
                progressStatus = 0;
                progress();
                //do it after 3 seconds
                handler.postDelayed(this, 3000);
            }
        }
    };

    handler.postDelayed(r, 0);


}



public void progress(){

    new Thread(new Runnable() {

        public void run() {
            long timerEnd = System.currentTimeMillis() + 3 * 1000;

            while (timerEnd >  System.currentTimeMillis()) {

                progressStatus = 3 - (int) (timerEnd - System.currentTimeMillis()) / 1000;
                // Update the progress bar

                handler.post(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        progressBar.setProgress(progressStatus);
                    }
                });

                try {
                    Thread.sleep(10);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    Log.w("App", "Progress thread cannot sleep");
                }
            }
        }
    }).start();

}


public void pauseWorkout(View view){
    handler.removeCallbacks(r);

}

public void resumeWorkout(View view){
    handler.postDelayed(r, 0);          
}
```

}

Comment: Have you tried handler.removeCallbacksAndMessages(null); instead of     handler.removeCallbacks(r); ?

Comment: No i have not - I will try that later when I have access to my code and will let you know.  Thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: Can you explain the difference between these two?  I am still learning.  Thank you!

Comment: RemoveCallbacksAndMessages(null) will simply clear all callbacks and messages. The full explanation is in the developer docs: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html#removeCallbacksAndMessages(java.lang.Object). I hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you! Will let you know if this works shortly.

Comment: Hey this didn't work. It does the same thing that its been doing.  It will pause, but in the middle of thread.  It waits for the progress bar to finish (3 seconds) before it pauses.  Any other ideas?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the while-loop in your progress() function is still working after you press your pause button.

Try the following: Create a global boolean that indicates you're in a paused or resuming state. Put it at the top of your code:

```
boolean resume = true;
```

Update your while condition in progress()

```
while (resume && timerEnd >  System.currentTimeMillis()) {
```

Update your workout functions:

```
public void pauseWorkout(View view){
    handler.removeCallbacks(r);
    resume = false;
}

public void resumeWorkout(View view){
    handler.postDelayed(r, 0); 
    resume = true;         
}
```

Comment: Ok so this partially works.  It works to stop the progessbar in the middle and resume.  The problem now is that when I resume, the imageview and textview get updated, when I don't want them to yet.  The progressbar is for 3 seconds, and the imagview and textview get updated after 3 seconds as well so this is all happening at the same time.

Comment: Well if you want the progressbar to update first, simply call progress() in resumeWorkout(). In order to delay the start of the ImageView update simply change the delay time in handler.postDelayed(r, delay); also in resumeWorkout().

Comment: I'm not sure what to put in the delay.  I tried `handler.postDelayed(r, timerEnd - System.currentTimeMillis());` and that does wait to change the textview and imageview, but is still not in sync with when the progressbar is finished.  I tried some way of getting the progress of the progressbar onPause, but I'm not sure how to implement that on resume.

Comment: Try calling progress() and then handler.postDelayed(r,3000); from resumeWorkout(). That's the last I can think of (I think it's more appropriate to post a new question on stackoverflow if this doesn't work as this is a different problem than your original question)